# What are the differences in use case between tabs and buffer in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

Especially in the case of having a buffline.

Comment: difference in use-cases? What exactly do you expect here?

Comment: This seems too broad in the sense of "Needs details/clarity" or "Needs focus" in https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions. There's also already a plethora of written material on tabs v. buffers (some of it quite old and on [so]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## windows

Within a tab you can split the viewport in windows to see multiple buffers at the same time.

Plugin use also windows within a tab to let you:

- Browse your files (e.g.: [nvim-tree](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua)) or
- Browse your tags (e.g.: [tagbar](https://github.com/preservim/tagbar)),
- Browse the undo tree (e.g. [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree))
- ...

With bufferline plugin you can switch the buffers visually (e.g. [bufferline](https://github.com/akinsho/bufferline.nvim)).

## tabs

When you create a tab you restart with a new independent layout a bit like a new Vim in Vim.

[Vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector) uses a new tab to create a new debugging layout when the debugger starts.

Some use one tab per project to have their specific window layout per project.